# Memorative art of Streams

Tags: stream, terminology

I'm trying to understand Streams.

How comparable is a stream (computer science) with a stream (water). This is how I picture them in my mind:

[image]

Now, I was wondering whether this thought is correct. If it's not a correct way, why isn't this a correct way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In information science, there is a specific meaning attached to the notation of two adjacent boxes, one with a value and another with an arrow pointing to another box pair.  It stands for a node of a singly-linked list (or just "linked list".)  This is an object which contains a value (otherwise known as payload) and a pointer to the next node of the list.

Linked lists have very little in common with streams.  True, both linked lists and streams are structures that can only be traversed sequentially, but the similarities end there.  Linked lists are not implemented as streams, and although in theory a stream may be implemented as a linked list, it would be inefficient, so it is usually not done this way.  When reading from a stream you can at any time only see the payload of the item that you have just read, you have no notion of a pointer to another item, and you cannot rearrange items by manipulating pointers.

So, no, this is not a correct way of picturing a stream in information science.

Generally, real-world metaphors are not useful at all for *understanding* information science entities.  You need to understand the definition of the entity exclusively in information science terms, and once you have achieved this, *then* you can use a real-world metaphor as a name for it, nothing more.

Take for example a "file".  Before computers, a file was a folder made of manila paper, containing papers.  With the advent of computers, a file is an array of bytes stored on the disk, representing data or code or both, following a format which may or may not be known, and which may be standard or it may only be interpretable by specialized software.  Knowing the old meaning of the word "file" does not help you at all in figuring out what a file is for computers. We just use the word "file" for convenience. We might even imagine a manila folder in our mind. But it is just a visual mnemonic, bearing no relation to reality.